# Is there a proper format to cite open source software?

Tags: research-process, citations, open-science

In my research I used a lot python libraries that I need to cite, I wonder if there is an accepted format for citing open-source software?

Do I just put them together with all other references? Do I create two separate references sections: "Article References", "Software References"? Or maybe there is another way to do it?

Just to be clear, I think I am good with the format of the citation itself, it is given [here](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/citing.html), but I am not sure where do I put those citations in a paper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every journal or venue may have its own recommendations, so check their style guides. However, I have never seen an article that has separate reference sections for software and articles. Just put them in one section together.